# Sharing itunes music between two computers

Tags: itunes, music, sharing

My girlfriend and I both use iTunes for our music. We have separate accounts and have iTunes on two different computers (she has a mac and I have a windows pc). I believe at one point people were able to share and copy music from one pc to another across the shared music network within iTunes. I'm having trouble doing so and was wondering if it's still possible to copy music from one pc to another with iTunes 11.0.2

If we can't copy music between iTunes anymore I guess we will have to use an external hard drive. I'd like to avoid this if we can so please let me know if you have any information on how to share music between two computers using iTunes 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is now called [Home Sharing](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4620). It's essentially the same as the original sharing feature, but it ties into your Apple ID to ensure that you can only share between your own computers.

In iTunes, just go to File > Home Sharing > Turn On Home Sharing and enter your Apple ID and password. Repeat the same steps on any computers you want to share with (up to 5) using the same Apple ID. Once you do so, all enabled computers will "see" each other and let you stream or copy music between them.

Comment: But what if we don't have the same Apple account ?

Comment: @Barth - It worked for me and my girlfriend and we don't have the same account

Comment: We actually did all of the above to enable home sharing but we don't seem to see each other's music. What did we miss?

Answer (score 0):

Open iTunes.
Select Home Sharing from where you choose between Music, Movies, and other kinds of media on the left side of iTunes.
If the Home Sharing icon is not visible, choose File > Devices > Turn On Home Sharing from the menu bar. (You can disable or enable Home Sharing for your computer using the File menu.)

Note: After enabling Home Sharing and clicking Done, Home Sharing is no longer visible until it detects another computer with Home Sharing enabled.

When prompted, enter your Apple ID account name and password:

Click "Turn on Home Sharing."

Use the above steps to enable Home Sharing on additional computers on your home network.

About:
Home Sharing is designed to be an easy way to either copy items from your iTunes library between your Macs or PCs in your home, or to share items from your iTunes library with your iPhone, iPad, iPod touch, and Apple TV (2nd and 3rd generation).